# React App > Sass File > What is ":local(.classSelector)" in this context?

Tags: reactjs, scope, sass

**Why:** I am dissecting another developers code to learn React

**Where this was found:** In a React app: [On GitHib](https://github.com/alexmngn/react-rock-paper-scissors/blob/master/src/components/Button/styles.scss)

- Folder Structure: components > Button
- Files Contained: index.jsx & styles.scss

**What I think it means:** It seems pretty obvious to me that this locks the scss styling to the local folder (specifically the element with the attribute of `styleName = Button`). However, I'm confused because I cannot find any other reference to this technique anywhere online. The closest thing I can find are articles talking about `:export` and `:import`.

What dependency allows this to happen?

Is this native to Sass?

Is this created by the dev to serve a specific purpose?

...and other such clarifying questions.

```
 :local(.Button) {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #27466E;
        padding: 7px 12px;

        &:hover {
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        &:disabled {
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: Man, after reading documentation for about 6 hours (not just about this) my eyes must have started failing me, because I looked at that very documentation and didn't see that. Thanks, @AndyRay